# Vuetify - restrict minimum value a slider can be moved to in v-slider

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using v-slider component of Vuetify and its been working great until I had a requiremenet wherein I need to set the minimum value beyond which slider should not be allowed to move.

For example, if v-slider has range from 0 to 10, I want to restrict thumb movement to minimum 2, so if a user tries to move thumb to anything less than 2, he should not be allowed to do so.

I did not find any configurable property to do so in vuetify v1.5. Is this achievable? Here is my code:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card flat color="transparent">  
      <v-card-text>
        <v-layout row>
          <v-flex class="pr-3">
            <v-slider
              v-model="slider"
              :max="max"
              :min="min"
            ></v-slider>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      min: 0,
      max: 10,
      slider: 6
    }
  }
})
```

Codepen - https://codepen.io/vishalgulati/pen/gOOMJvX

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<v-slider
      v-model="slider"
      :max="max"
      :min="min"
      @input="catchInput"
      :key="sliderKey"
>
</v-slider>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      min: 0,
      max: 10,
      slider: 6,
      sliderKey: 0

    }
  },
  methods: {
    catchInput(e){
      if (e < 3){
        this.slider = 2
        this.sliderKey++
      }
    }
  }
})
```

What this does is catch the input and check if it is 2 or less. In this case the `catchInput` method sets the value of the slider to 2 and forces a rerender of the slider with the `sliderKey`. Hope this is clear.